# XText: qualified name vs. method

Tags: java, xtext

I am having a problem in getting XText to generate a parser that can differentiate, Java-style, between qualified names and methods.

Consider, for example, a statement of the form:

```
x.y.z();
```

This could be either:

- calling static method z() in class y in package x
- calling member method z() on field y in object x

How do I use XText to be able to handle things like the following (slightly nonsensical but totally semantically sensible) Java expression:

```
java.util.Collections.EMPTY_LIST.size() + "foo".concat("bar").length();
```

which currently gives me a parse error:

```
SEVERE: Error at line 5: mismatched input '.' expecting '(' [Thu Dec 04 14:45:20 CST 2014]
SEVERE: Error at line 5: missing EOF at '.' [Thu Dec 04 14:45:20 CST 2014]
```

The relevant fragments of XText code, as they currently stand:

```
grammar it.unibo.alchemist.language.FieldCalculus with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals
import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore

[...]

QualifiedName: ID ('.' ID)* ;

FunctionCall returns Expression:
    (function=QualifiedName)'('args=ExprList?')'
;

Expression:
    Logical ';'?
;

Logical returns Expression:
 [... order of operations build-up to ...]

Postfix returns Expression:
    Primary
    ({Expression.left=current}(
        (name='.' methodName=ID '(' (args=ExprList)? ')')
    ))?
;

Primary returns Expression:
 (v = (VarVal | FunctionCall | Rep | NBR | If) | '(' Expression ')')
;
```